# CMS Collection doesn't show custom object fields in Field Mappings

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page, salesforce-cms

I created a custom object in Salesforce and am now attempting to display them in an Experience Cloud site using the CMS Collection component.

Within the CMS Collection component settings I only see the Name field for my custom object in the dropdown for all the Field Mappings (or just None for some of them). I can set the Name field for one of the mapping and see data, but can't map any of my other custom fields.

The custom object has Test, Date, and URL fields so I would expect them to show up in various Field Mappings (due to matching Data types).

The object is marked as deployed and it should have read permissions (it does for system admin and the custom profile I created for users of the experience cloud site).

Any ideas on how I can see my custom fields in the CMS Collection field mapping?

Answer (score 1):

To map fields to a CMS Collection, you must add these fields (either standard or custom) to the list view you are using in the CMS Collection.

I don't know if all field types can be mapped to a CMS Collection, but as per my experience: URL, text, long text area and formula fields can be.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). You stated that you "must add these fields", but then you did not list any fields. Unless you mean the fields in the second paragraph, but those do not sound like "must" adds. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/358536/edit) your answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You should go to the gear icon in your object and click "Select fields to display"